# Merging dataset which was split to comply with upload size limits

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have about 5GB of CSV data I've split into parts to comply with QuickSight's 1GB file size limit.

Now that it's in QuickSight SPICE, how do I merge this data back to its original form?

The obvious feature to use is "Add dataset" to an existing dataset. But this only supports joins, which merge rows together horizontally. I need to merge the data vertically.

My *hope* is the solution is supported by QuickSight and this is a stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the capacity of your spice.

Go to account setting *Manage Quicksight>SPICE capacity* and it will show you the option of "purchase more capacity", but remember, you will be leaving the free tier layer.